# canDeactivate in case of returning first false, next time true navigates twice

Tags: angular, guard

I have some kind of "Unsaved changes" pop-up, where the user can cancel the back navigation. In this case, when the user clicks cancel (`canDeactivate` guard returns false), but then tries to navigate back (`canDeactivate` is called) and the user selects "leave without saving" (`canDeactivate` guard returns true), the navigation back occurs twice.

component

```ts
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    return !this.unsavedChangesAvailable;
  }
```

guard

```ts
  canDeactivate(
    component: BLAComponent,
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (!component.canDeactivate()) {
      this.unsavedChangesModal = this.dialog.open(UnsavedChangesModalComponent, {
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto'
      });
      return this.unsavedChangesModal.afterClosed().pipe(
        map((choice: boolean) => {
          return choice;
        }));
    } else {
      return of(true);
    }
  }
```

modal

```html
 <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="false" cdkFocusInitial>
    {{ 'EDITOR.UNSAVED_CHANGES_MODAL.CANCEL' | translate }}</button>
    <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">{{
      'EDITOR.UNSAVED_CHANGES_MODAL.LEAVE_WITHOUT_SAVE' | translate }}
    </button>
```

The problem occurs in Angular 6, but also in the last version 8. I have updated it, because I thought the problem was solved (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+candeactivate+twice), but the update did not solve the problem.

Comment: What made you think it was solved? The issue's still open: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13586

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for this.
Create a flag in component and use it to show and hide the popup inside the guard.

```
canDeactivate(component: PreventDiscardChangesAwareComponent): Promise<boolean> {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (!!component && !!component.preventDiscardChanges && component.isDiscardChangesPreventionNeeded) {
    if (!!component.isDiscardChangesPreventionNeeded() && !component.popupShowed) {
      this.store.dispatch(new HideProgressSpinnerAction());
      component.preventDiscardChanges().subscribe((result) => {
        this.store.dispatch(new ShowProgressSpinnerAction());
        if (result) {
          resolve(true);
          component.popupShowed = true;
        } else {
          resolve(false);
        }
      });
    } else {
      resolve(true);
    }
  } else {
    resolve(true);
  }
});
```

}

and inside the component add a new flag 'popupShowed' with false